# Display appendix chapter like: "Appendix", and sections like "Appendix A: My appendix title"

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering, chapters, appendices

I wish to make my appendix chapter like: "Appendix", and sections like "Appendix A: My appendix title" "Appendix B: My second title" by writing:

```
\chapter{Appendix}
\section{My appendix title}
\section{My second title}
```

My first problem is that the "Appendix A:" - section numeration thing and the section name is on top of each other. Here's an image of the problem:

[image]

With this I have used the package `\usepackage[title]{appendix}`, and the commands:

```
\begin{appendices}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Appendix}
\gdef\thechapter{\arabic{equation}}
\gdef\thesection{\appendixname\Alph{section}}
\end{appendices}
```

I want the chapter counter to continue from the content and not start on 
`0`, but be in this example `2`, and also the section to be like:

```
\gdef\thesection{Appendix \Alph{section}\colon\ } %And then get section name and the dots
```

By this line I get an error message, like its too long or something, because if I don't make the line so long I don't get the error. Don't know why.

If I use the package or not, and just say: `\appendix` is the same by me, I just tried both to see if I manage to get it as I want.

Comment: Which document class are you using? I uploaded the image for you. [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: So you have *two* appendices, and yet you only want a chapter with the title "Appendix" (in singular)? That's not what one would expect.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina
The class is made by my school. Thanks!

I have many more appendices that will be in section 3, 4, 5 and so on. The document is divided into nine chapters, so I think it looks much cleaner this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `subappendices` environment, the `titletoc` package option, and redefine `\thesection`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\backmatter
\begin{subappendices}
\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}
\chapter{Appendices}
\section{My first title}
\section{My second title}
\end{subappendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This did exactly what I was looking for. This isn't a book, so I couldn't use \backmatter, but I think it looks good this way. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I can't press the button to say that the answer is useful, I got too few rep points. I'll press it when I got enough :)